# Why is this content invisible when prepended or html'd?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to prepend a string but it is invisible for some reason. Anyone know what is wrong with it?

```
$('#someelement').prepend('<div id="chunk" chunk_id="302724de111fd8fd4a7.92282758">
<a shoutbox_id="302724de111fd8fd4a7.92282758" id="show-replies">
<img src="images/show_more.png"></a>
<a shoutbox_id="302724de111fd8fd4a7.92282758" id="reply">Add Comment</a>
<li class="shoutbox-list-creator" id="list-13">
<span class="shoutbox-list-nick">
<a href="statistics.php?user=g">g</a>
</span>
<span class="date" id="1306595842">  0 seconds ago
</span><br>
<span class="msg">i said</span><br />
<span class="clear"></span>
</li><hr>
</div>');
```

Comment: what type of element is `#someelement`?

Comment: Did you check it was correctly inserted into the html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put all the HTML on a single line (remove the line breaks).

The other choice is to put a backslash at the end of every line. This will work:

```
$('#someelement').prepend('<div id="chunk" chunk_id="302724de111fd8fd4a7.92282758"> \
<a shoutbox_id="302724de111fd8fd4a7.92282758" id="show-replies">           \
<img src="images/show_more.png"></a>                                       \
<a shoutbox_id="302724de111fd8fd4a7.92282758" id="reply">Add Comment</a>   \
<li class="shoutbox-list-creator" id="list-13">                            \
<span class="shoutbox-list-nick">                                          \
<a href="statistics.php?user=g">g</a>                                      \
</span>                                                                    \
<span class="date" id="1306595842">  0 seconds ago                         \
</span><br>                                                                \
<span class="msg">i said</span><br />                                      \
<span class="clear"></span>                                                \
</li><hr>                                                                  \
</div>');
```

Comment: Thanks thirtydot, appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The content is never added to the DOM, that's why it is not visible.

Running the code gives:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

You cannot split your string over multiple lines like this.
It works if everything is on one line: http://jsfiddle.net/JCTpG/

Answer (score 3):

When I put everything on one line it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I need to copy my urls better next time :)